Maximum column norm of random $A^{-1}B$
Suppose that $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ Gaussian matrix (each component i.i.d. normal distributed with mean 0 and variance 1). Let $b$ be a $n$-Gaussian vector. Then it could be easily proven that the median of $||A^{-1}b||_2$ is roughly $O(\sqrt{n})$, i.e. $||A^{-1}b||_2\le O(\sqrt{n})$ with high probability.
Similarly, if $B$ is an $n$ by $n$ Gaussian matrix, then it could be proven that $||A^{-1}B||_2\le O(n)$ with high probability.
However, I did some experiments and found that
$$\max_{j\in[n]}||(A^{-1}B)_{\cdot j}||_2 \ ,$$
the maximum column $l_2$ norm of $A^{-1}B$, looks like to be bounded by $O(\sqrt{n})$ instead of $O(n)$. This is so interesting because it is of the same order of the norm for only one column.
Does anyone know how to prove a high-probability upper bound result of the maximum column norm?

I think it is more likely to be $\asymp\sqrt n,\ln n$. For $n$ not too large, numerical experiments may not detect the log factor.

I see. That is still very interesting for me. Do you know any references or evidence for this result? Or are there any suggestions on how should I prove it? Thanks so much.

Unfortunately, I don't have such references or evidence.

Still, thank you so much for providing this intuition.

What is the median for you ? The mean or (50% below , 50% above).

Hi loup, that median means the median of the many samples of ||A^{-1}b||_2. Since the bound is an upper bound, it actually means the smaller half.  (I am curious about a similar result of max_j || ^{-1} _j ||_2.   )

We write about the median -not the mean which is significantly greater- of
$||A^{-1}b||_2$.
I am surprised by the conjecture made by @Iosif Pinelis according to which the considered median $m_n$ would be in $O(\sqrt{n}log(n))$.
Note that $m_1=1$. I did random tests according to which $m_n$ seems to behave at infinity like $k\sqrt{n}$.
More precisely, $m_{60},m_{100},m_{140}$ are $\approx k\sqrt{n}$, where $k\in (1.46,1.47)$.
I have no argument that would justify this result. Note, however, that it is often more difficult to evaluate a median than an average.
